# Extend TinyWM in Python

Tags: python, xlib

I have this C code from TinyWM:

```
XGrabKey(dsp, XKeysymToKeycode(dsp, XStringToKeysym("F1")), Mod4Mask, DefaultRootWindow(dsp), True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);

...
        XNextEvent(dsp, &ev);
        if(ev.type == KeyPress){
            if(ev.xbutton.button == XKeysymToKeycode(dsp,XStringToKeysym("F1"))){
                system("xterm &");
            }
...
```

I want in python

Comment: just need replace ev.xbutton.button with python

Comment: ev = dsp.next_event()

 if ev.type == X.KeyPress:
  if ev.detail == dsp.keysym_to_keycode(XK.string_to_keysym("F1")):
   subprocess.call(['xterm'], shell=True)